# Disabling Polymer gestures on custom web component

Tags: angularjs, web, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I noticed that Polymer *"**consumes**"* gestures on my own web components.

I have 2 web components on my page: google-map (Polymer based) and animated button (native one, written by myself, not using any frameworks).

They are imported in this way:

[image]

google-map folder has the following structure:

[image]

Angular **ng-click** is defined on animated button:

```
<animated-button-web-component ng-click="fireEvent('click');" data-src="" data-src-click="" data-src-hover="" data-text="foo" class=""></animated-button-web-component>
```

When I use Chrome in regular mode **click** event is fired as expected but when I use Chrome in the **device mode** the similar **touch** event is not fired from the animated button. If I remove google-map completely from the page it starts working.

Do you have any idea how to **"isolate"** Polymer so it doesn't interfere with the events in the document?

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: Have you tried `on-tap` instead of `ng-click`?

Comment: It doesn't fire an event for me. Is it a pure HTML attribute?

Still even if it works I don't want Polymer to interfere in other than google-map element. I want ng-click to work on animated button like it works without Polymer.

Comment: No it's not a pure HTML attribute. Is it possible to start a jsFiddle for this?